# plotting a simple circle from a mesh

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have a mesh grid and a function on the coordinates using `numpy.mgrid`.

```
xx, yy = np.mgrid[:100, :100]
circle = (xx-50)**2 + (yy-50)**2
```

How can I plot the circle coordinates in a simple 2d circle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just create a mask from `circle` and then easy ploting, for example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

xx, yy = np.mgrid[:100, :100]
circle = (xx-50)**2 + (yy-50)**2
donut  = (circle < (2500 + 50)) & (circle > (2500 - 50))

plt.imshow(donut)
plt.show()
```

Yet this doesn't give a perfect circle but a digitized one:

[image]

Is that what you wished for?

Or you can just plot the contour like:

```
plt.contour(xx,yy,circle,[50])
plt.show()
```

---

Another option is using `meshgird` instead and plot only the contour like the following:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = np.linspace(30, 70, 1000)
y = np.linspace(30, 70, 1000)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)
F = (X-50)**2 + (Y-50)**2
plt.contour(X,Y,F,[50])
plt.show()
```

Which give the following:

[image]

Comment: @Nikola it's just the position of the contour, you can set it to any value of the circle. https://matplotlib.org/3.3.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.contour.html So setting it to 50 will plot a circle with a radius of 25